# Crashing with VNDK

Tags: pi-3b+, android-things

I have 2 raspberry pi 3's, so far as I know identical. I'm running Android Things on them.

I have my app on a sim and it works fine in one pi. Putting the sim in the other pi, I see the app initialising, and then it stops before it is fully loaded, with this line in the log file:

D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.

Is one of my pi's bust? How can a sim give different results in different (same model) pi's?

I'm reluctant to just swap pi's in my system as the pio's are all wired up, so it would be quite a fiddle swapping all those wires. I'd really like to get the wired up pi working too.

Thanks for any advice